# Enable Impala Impersonation on Superset

Tags: impala, apache-superset

Is there a way to make the logged user (on superset) to make the queries on impala?
I tried to enable the "Impersonate the logged on user" option on Databases but with no success because all the queries run on impala with superset user.

[image: Configuration here]

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to achieve the same! This will not completely answer this question since it does not still work but I want to share my research in order to maybe help another soul that is trying to use this instrument outside very basic use cases.

I went deep in the code and I found out that impersonation **is not** implemented for Impala. So you cannot achieve this from the UI. I found out this PR https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/4699 that for whatever reason was never merged into the codebase and tried to copy&paste code in my Superset version (1.1.0) but it didn't work. Adding some logs I can see that the configuration with the impersonation is updated, but then the actual Impala query is with the user I used to start the process.

As you can imagine, I am a complete noob at this. However I found out that the impersonation thing happens when you create a **cursor** and there is a constructor parameter in which you can pass the impersonation configuration.

I managed to correctly (at least to my understanding) implement impersonation for the SQL lab part.

In the `sql_lab.py` class you have to add in the `execute_sql_statements` method the following lines

```
    with closing(engine.raw_connection()) as conn:
        # closing the connection closes the cursor as well
        cursor = conn.cursor(**database.cursor_kwargs)
```

where cursor_kwargs is defined in `db_engine_specs/impala.py` as the following

```
    @classmethod
    def get_configuration_for_impersonation(cls, uri, impersonate_user, username):
        logger.info(
            'Passing Impala execution_options.cursor_configuration for impersonation')
        return {'execution_options': {
            'cursor_configuration': {'impala.doas.user': username}}}

    @classmethod
    def get_cursor_configuration_for_impersonation(cls, uri, impersonate_user,
                                                   username):
        logger.debug('Passing Impala cursor configuration for impersonation')
        return {'configuration': {'impala.doas.user': username}}
```

Finally, in `models/core.py` you have to add the following bit in the `get_sqla_engine` def

```
 params = extra.get("engine_params", {}) # that was already there just for you to find out the line

self.cursor_kwargs = self.db_engine_spec.get_cursor_configuration_for_impersonation(
            str(url), self.impersonate_user, effective_username) # this is the line I added

...

 params.update(self.get_encrypted_extra()) # already there
 
#new stuff
configuration = {}
configuration.update(
            self.db_engine_spec.get_configuration_for_impersonation(
                str(url),
                self.impersonate_user,
                effective_username))

if configuration:
   params.update(configuration)
```

As you can see I just shamelessy pasted the code from the PR. However this kind of works only for the SQL lab as I already said. For the dashboards there is an entirely different way of querying Impala that I did not still find out.

This means that queries for the dashboards are handled in a different way and there isn't something like this

```
 with closing(engine.raw_connection()) as conn:
        # closing the connection closes the cursor as well
        cursor = conn.cursor(**database.cursor_kwargs)
```

My gut (and debugging) feeling is that you need to first understand the sqlalchemy part and extend a new ImpalaEngine class that uses a custom cursor with the impersonation conf. Or something like that, however it is not simple (if we want to call this simple) as the sql_lab part. So, the trick is to find out where the query is executed and create a cursor with the impersonation configuration. Easy, isnt'it ?

I hope that this could shed some light to you and the others that have this issue. Let me know if you did find out another way to solve this issue, or if this comment was useful.

## Update: something really useful

A colleague of mine succesfully implemented impersonation with impala without touching any superset related, but instead working directly with the `impyla` lib. A [PR](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/issues/456) was open with the code to change. You can apply the patch directly in the impyla src used by superset. You have to edit both `dbapi.py` and `hiveserver2.py`.

As a reminder: we are still testing this and we do not know if it works with different accounts using the same superset instance.